# one storyboard for iPhone 3.5 and 4 inches

Tags: storyboard, xcode5

you can set the storyboard to suit iphone screens 3.5 inches and 4 inches or have to make a storyboard separately for each one of them?

whether to make one for each device, which is the device knows which interface load

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following discussions and one thing is clear that you need to use AutoLayouting to achieve this:

[how can I use one storyboard for 4" and 3.5" iphone screens with autolayout (ios6 + ios7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658140/how-can-i-use-one-storyboard-for-4-and-3-5-iphone-screens-with-autolayout-ios)

[Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes in Storyboards (3.5 and 4 inch screens)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132094/supporting-multiple-screen-sizes-in-storyboards-3-5-and-4-inch-screens)