# Decrease the gap between labels when in Landscape orientation in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, orientation, constraints

I'm placing 5 UILabels one under another. In portrait orientation the gap between them lets say is 50px. When i switch to landscape orientation i want that gap to be decreased to 20 for ex. Is there any solution to solve this with constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744287/ios-autolayout-how-to-set-two-different-distances-between-views-depends-on-th?answertab=active#tab-top). After putting some constraints, first we need to make an outlet for a desired constraint for changing and then just edit its constant.