# Is there any option to change constraints in storyboard for iphone 4 or 5 in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, constraints

I want make an app to iPhone 4 and 5, but when I add the constraints in storyBoard, this only show correctly in iphone 5. In iphone 4 some component hidden other.. Is there any form to apply this constraints to iphone 4 and other constraints to iPhone 5?

Comment: It's possible that you are setting constraints with fixed values that don't work on smaller screens.

Comment: How can check this? I have in viewController of storyBoard in Simulated metrics -> Size: iPhone 4-inch, should I change this to iPhone 3.5 inch?

Comment: set your constrains to left right and bottom not to top that's should help

Comment: yes you can, you find here the solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37325714/2477632 hope that helps