# How to specify different sizes for iPhone 6+, 6 and 5?

Tags: ios

I want to make the view look almost same on each of iPhone 6+, 6 and 5.
In the attached picture, I mean, that, for example, "Cancel" button should be 30 pixels from left edge of screen in iPhone 5, 35 px in 6 and 45 px for 6+ and the similar for other elements.

How can specific constrains sizes be placed for each type of it? If I use proportions in constrains, so buttons grow, but their sizes not controlled and spaces between elements I cant change also. Size classes with specific constrains sizes I also can`t use, because cW aH is for 5 and 6 iphones the same. (as I understood).

I can`t figure out how to do it.
How usually different designs for 6 and 6+ managed now?

[image]

Comment: Watch the WWDC video on adaptive interfaces on iOS8.

Comment: Done it, but did not find answers for my case :( 
I dont use ipad and dont rotate view. 
Just want to specify spaces between elements for different iphones.

Comment: you can checkout my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37325714/2477632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to pick 30, 35 and 45px ? Is there a reason for that pixelish placement ?

---

You can use more flexible constraints by using their multiply value instead of the constant.

The constraints adjusts themselves depending on the superview dimensions.

iPhone5 **-** iPhone 6 **-** iPhone 6+ **-** iPad **-** iPhone4 landscape
[image: Constraints demo]

Note how my *center X alignment constraints* are configured:

[image]

---

[image]

You can see that the values behaves kind of strangely, sometimes multiplier is > 1, sometimes it's between 1 and 2, or < 1 depending on the order of `First Item` and `Second Item`. You still can swap their order by clicking on them and selecting `Reverse First And Second Item`.

Comment: I have layout prepared by designer. At real I provided with 6+ exact sizes, but cant make them looks good for 6 and 5s. 

First approach was in recalculating for 5s and internal scaling by device, which applied if I dont use splash screens for 6/6+. I was disired this result, bit it is not right.

Now I want the same but backwards - put 6+ sizes and scale them proportionally for 6/5s, but got only mess. I used internal proportions in view cnstraints, but still not control prefered sizes and positions for elements. Thats it.

Comment: Hm.. You can always make an outlet of your constraints and set their constant when loading your view, like in [the edit of CeceXX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28093987/1392046). Should fit more to your needs.

Answer (score 6):

You can't target specific models of iPhone with Auto Layout. It's not meant for that. Auto Layout was built to avoid this. However, here are two workarounds:

### Updated for iOS 9 and above

Use stack views. They're great for this kind of layout.

### First option

Place an invisible `UIView` and create top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints attached to the `Superview`. After that, place your objects (they can be `UIImageViews`, `UILabels` and the list goes on) inside the `UIView` you have just placed. Now create top and bottom constraints that connect your objects to the `UIView`.

I created a demo to show you how it's done. As you will see, buttons have different sizes depending on the screen's size. Download the demo from [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aecn78q6bsyb06g/Demo.zip?dl=0) link.

### Second option

You could create and modify constraints programmatically. Create a `NSLayoutConstraint` and adjust the `constant` of it depending on the user's device:

```
var myConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: myButton,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraint(myConstraint)

if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 375 {
    // iPhone 6
    myConstraint.constant = 10
} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 414 {
    // iPhone 6+
    myConstraint.constant = 15
}
```

Comment: *cough* as a general rule, never do direct comparisons on floats, as per the EDIT. In this case probably pick between 6 and 6+ with a > 395 or something similarly intermediary — apart from the floating point issue it'll make your code most likely to do something sensible if a new size comes along. But, you know, pedantry attack. I'm still going to vote positively for this answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt figure out  how to deal with it. Iam using XIBs and all controls now placed on internal view. It dont wont work.
And I still cant specify exact  values for spaces for different iphone devices without rotation.

Comment: How does it answers the question ? Be careful, UIScreen is interface oriented on iOS8, that means the width is no longer 375 on iPhone 6 landscape. **edit:** Oh, I see for the orange view in your example... It's a bit tricky !