# iOS swift Autolayout constraint for iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I find it difficult to still consider the screen size of iPhone 4s when I design the ui of my app in Xcode storyboard. I usually meet the case that for iPhone 7 I get much place left, but not enough place for iPhone 4s. is there a way to specially set some  constraints for iPhone 4s? thank you all.

Comment: You can check for what model is running, but this is usually frowned upon. While I'm in the same boat - my adaptive layout is **reallllly** tight on the 4s - the right thing to do is keep your constraints as universal as possible. I managed to set some label font sizes just a bit below the HIG guidelines (they suggest 11 point minimum) to get things to fit. Truth is, you never know - Apple may decide next year to come back with a 4 inch phone for their 10th anniversary of the iPhone.

Comment: In storyboard you can set constraints based on the size class of the phone. I haven't used storyboards in a while but I know they made it easier to deal with in xcode 8. There is a ton of stuff out there on learning how to set constraints using size classes.

Comment: Finally I found the solution here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818962/size-class-specifically-for-portrait-3-5-inch-iphone-4s-xcode-6