# Why does this autolayout extension fail when you "Vary for Traits" in the storyboard?

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I actually updated the extension below (found here: [Size class specifically for portrait 3.5 inch (iPhone 4S) XCode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818962/size-class-specifically-for-portrait-3-5-inch-iphone-4s-xcode-6/57621783#57621783) ) for Swift 5.0, and it works *except* when the constraint being modified has a "vary for traits" property and I cannot figure out why?

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint
{
    //We use a simple inspectable to allow us to set a value for iphoneSE / 5s.
    @IBInspectable var iPhoneSE_PortraitConstant: CGFloat
        {
        set{
            //Only apply value to iphone SE and 5s devices.
             if (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height < 660 && UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width < 330)
            {
                self.constant = newValue;
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return self.constant;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that Xcode is first finding the constraint and them seeing if it has a Vary for Traits addition and for this reason ignores the extension? How can I get past this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on quick testing, it appears the order goes like this:

- XIB gets loaded (Storyboard is effectively a big XIB)
- User Defined Run Time Attributes are applied (this would be your `iPhoneSE_PortraitConstant`) which sets the ***`.constant`*** of the constraint
- Auto-layout does its thing
- Auto-layout sets the ***`.constant`*** of the constraint, based on Traits, if they exist (it does ***not*** set the `iPhoneSE_PortraitConstant` property)

So, that extension won't work if the constraint itself has trait variations.

The key, there, is *the constraint itself*.

To get this approach to work, instead of setting trait variations on the constraint, set trait variations on the view and have two (or more) separate constraints. Then set the `iPhoneSE_PortraitConstant` on the constraint(s) as needed.