# Suggest logic for dynamically add Label and Textfields using Autolayout constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

Working code is here [Manage UITextField's dynamic position using auto layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517069/manage-uitextfields-dynamic-position-using-auto-layout) for *generating dynamic TextFields* but I also want a **label** (dynamically added) before the every textField. Thanks!

Comment: Best way for this is use UIStackView. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/1390/uistackview#t=201703101129055813853

Answer (score 1):

You Just Take The textFields Height Constant and textFields Top Constant ...where ever you are hiding that textfield height do must 0 and the under textfield top constant give 0 it will work..

we do not do any functionality ..the simulator show like this..[image]

after write these two lines of the code the simulator working like this .

```
_fieldThreeHeight.constant = 0;
_fieldFourTop.constant = 0;
```

[image]