# Change the value of constraint for only iPhone 4 in IB

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

How I can change the value of a constraint on only one device.
For example, I want to display a button with 400px height for all iPhones except iPhone 4 where I would display it with 300px ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution is to create new class inherit from NSLayoutConstraint class and add the properties below, like that you will have the possibility to change the constant, the  multiplier and also to deactivate the constraint for each device **and all this in the interface builder** :

[image]

```
import UIKit

/**
 * This class used to modify easly the constraint for each device iPhone 4, iPhone 5, iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 Plus
 * You can modify the constant, the multiplier and also active / deactive the constraint for each device
 * You should modify this properties only in the storyboard
 */
@IBDesignable
public class LayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

    // MARK: 3¨5

    /**
     * The constant for device with 3.5 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 3¨5_const: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if CGRectGetMaxY(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) == 480 {
                constant = 3¨5_const
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The multiplier for device with 3.5 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 3¨5_multip: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if CGRectGetMaxY(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) == 480 {
                self.setValue(3¨5_multip, forKey: "multiplier")
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The boolean to active deative constraint for device with 3.5 insh size
     * The default value is true.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 3¨5_active: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if CGRectGetMaxY(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) == 480 {
                active = 3¨5_active
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: 4¨0

    /**
     * The constant for device with 4.0 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨0_const: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if CGRectGetMaxY(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) == 568 {
                constant = 4¨0_const
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The multiplier for device with 4.0 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨0_multip: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if CGRectGetMaxY(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) == 568 {
                self.setValue(4¨0_multip, forKey: "multiplier")
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The boolean to active deative constraint for device with 4.0 insh size
     * The default value is true.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨0_active: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if CGRectGetMaxY(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) == 568 {
                active = 4¨0_active
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: 4¨7

    /**
     * The constant for device with 4.7 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨7_const: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if CGRectGetMaxY(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) == 667 {
                constant = 4¨7_const
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The multiplier for device with 4.7 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨7_multip: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if CGRectGetMaxY(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) == 667 {
                self.setValue(4¨7_multip, forKey: "multiplier")
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The boolean to active deative constraint for device with 4.7 insh size
     * The default value is true.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨7_active: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if CGRectGetMaxY(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) == 667 {
                active = 4¨7_active
            }
        }
    }
    // MARK: 5¨5

    /**
     * The constant for device with 5.5 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 5¨5_const: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if CGRectGetMaxY(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) == 736 {
                constant = 5¨5_const
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The multiplier for device with 5.5 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 5¨5_multip: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if CGRectGetMaxY(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) == 736 {
                self.setValue(5¨5_multip, forKey: "multiplier")
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The boolean to active / deactive constraint for device with 5.5 insh size
     * The default value is true.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 5¨5_active: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if CGRectGetMaxY(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) == 736 {
                active = 5¨5_active
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @HamzaGhazouani Does it auto-update when we change values in IB?

Comment: @BadhanGanesh When you change the value in IB, you should run the project to see the result

Answer (score 0):

You can take outlet for your constraint and change its value according to the device you are running on.i.e if iphone4 then 300px else 400px using "**constant**" property of outlet

Answer (score 0):

You can take outlet of height constraint of that button. then you can detect device if it is iphone 4 then you can change it's constraint's outlet's `constant` something like,

```
   self.heightConstraint.constant = 300;
```

For connect outlet of constraint just `ctrl + drag from that constraint to class`

You can detect device by getting screensize.

```
if ([ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 480.00) {

      NSLog(@"this is iphn 4");
      self.heightConstraint.constant = 300;
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

First Create object of button height constraint(btnConstHeight)

```
if ([ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 480.00) {
    self.btnConstHeight.constant = 300;
}
else{
    self.btnConstHeight.constant = 400;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 Version of @Hamza 's answer

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

/**
 * This class used to modify easly the constraint for each device iPhone 4, iPhone 5, iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 Plus
 * You can modify the constant, the multiplier and also active / deactive the constraint for each device
 * You should modify this properties only in the storyboard
 */
@IBDesignable
public class LayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

    // MARK: 3¨5

    /**
     * The constant for device with 3.5 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 3¨5_const: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {

            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 480 {
                constant = 3¨5_const
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The multiplier for device with 3.5 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 3¨5_multip: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 480 {
                self.setValue(3¨5_multip, forKey: "multiplier")
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The boolean to active deative constraint for device with 3.5 insh size
     * The default value is true.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 3¨5_active: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 480 {
                isActive = 3¨5_active
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: 4¨0

    /**
     * The constant for device with 4.0 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨0_const: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 568 {
                constant = 4¨0_const
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The multiplier for device with 4.0 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨0_multip: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 568 {
                self.setValue(4¨0_multip, forKey: "multiplier")
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The boolean to active deative constraint for device with 4.0 insh size
     * The default value is true.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨0_active: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 568 {
                isActive = 4¨0_active
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: 4¨7

    /**
     * The constant for device with 4.7 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨7_const: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 667 {
                constant = 4¨7_const
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The multiplier for device with 4.7 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨7_multip: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 667 {
                self.setValue(4¨7_multip, forKey: "multiplier")
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The boolean to active deative constraint for device with 4.7 insh size
     * The default value is true.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 4¨7_active: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 667 {
                isActive = 4¨7_active
            }
        }
    }
    // MARK: 5¨5

    /**
     * The constant for device with 5.5 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 5¨5_const: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 736 {
                constant = 5¨5_const
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The multiplier for device with 5.5 insh size
     * The default value is the value of the constant of the constraint.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 5¨5_multip: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 736 {
                self.setValue(5¨5_multip, forKey: "multiplier")
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The boolean to active / deactive constraint for device with 5.5 insh size
     * The default value is true.
     */
    @IBInspectable
    public var 5¨5_active: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY == 736 {
                isActive = 5¨5_active
            }
        }
    }
}
```